# SVG animation that should be simple

Tags: animation, drawing, svg

I have a simple SVG drawing with an animation.
 What I have is two objects moving in a circle around a common center, with different rotation rates. I want to draw a line connecting the two objects.

The SVG drawing is as follows:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <circle cx="200" cy="150" r="5" fill="blue">
        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            begin="0s"
            dur="30s"
            type="rotate"
            from="90 150 150"
            to="-90 150 150"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
        />
    </circle>
    <circle cx="226.2" cy="150" r="5" fill="red">
        <animateTransform
            attributeName="transform"
            begin="0s"
            dur="30s"
            type="rotate"
            from="47.8 150 150"
            to="-47.8 150 150"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
        />
    </circle>
</svg>
```

It's easy enough to calculate the positions of the objects at any given time, but SVG doesn't seem to make it easy to do it this way. 
I'm convinced that this could be done with a couple of rotations and maybe a scaling, but I can't wrap my mind around how it would work.

So, anyone know what to do?

Comment: btw what client/browser are you using to show the animation?

Comment: Safari and Firefox. Is it not showing up correctly for you?

Comment: Oops. I realized this didn't work properly in Firefox. Fixed now.

Comment: Can't see an animation in firefox. safari/chrome/opera are ok!

Comment: Apparently Firefox does not support animations in SVG yet, from what I can tell. I don't know how I tricked myself into thinking it was working earlier.

Comment: now to the problem: not an easy one! must it be svg own's animation - or can it also be a javascript animation? As just with roatation and scaling I would say it's not possible...

Comment: You said "It's easy enough to calculate the positions of the objects at any given time" - Is it?? Actually I can't manage it.

Comment: You use the equations for uniform circular motion. For the blue one: 
x = 150 + 50 cos (pi * time / 60 seconds)<br />
y = 150 - 50 sin (pi * time / 60 seconds). <br />
For the red one: <br />
x = 150 + 76.2 cos(1.88 * pi * time / 60 seconds)<br />
y = 150 - 76.2 sin(1.88 * pi * time / 60 seconds)<br />